# check all files in directory in windows script

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to execute a windows script against bunch of files in a directory. This script checks the format of the files it it is not good, I need to write to the log.txt file so that I can go back and fix each file.

I tried this:

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (testscript -l "%f") >>logs.txt
```

I need to now the file names as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of `forfiles /?` shows something similar to this:

```
FORFILES /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE testscript.exe @file"
```

Comment: this kinda works, can you only print out the files that have errors. Errors would have this text in it "invalid"

Comment: @user1471980: you can add a `| findstr "invalid"` at the end, this filters the output on that particular word.